# SWT ComboViewer with ContentProposal and Pagination Control (large anmount of data)

Tags: combobox, pagination, eclipse-rcp, nebula, large-data

I have implemented a ComboViewer that also uses content proposal (ContentProposalAdapter) functionality in Eclipse RCP application (using SWT). User is able to type first letter of e.g. a street and he gets all valid proposals e.g. streets that starts with 'Mac'. It works really great. Now I am facing  additional problem. Number of data to show in this combo can be very big. Now I got almost 200000 records to show. Creating Combo element in GUI takes forever and it crashes my RCP application. I thought about introducing pagination control for this ComboViewer. I would like it to work very similar to this ExtJs solution:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/form/forum-search.html

What I was able to find is Nebula Pagination Control (https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/pagination/pagination.php) 
I found just examples where it is user in grid, but not in a combo. There is something like PageableTable, but it is something way different that I need. Does anyone have any example of combining pagination control with ComboViewer? Maybe some other idea, not necessarily Nebula  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `Text` field with `AutoCompleteField` and `TextContentAdapter`.

```java
new AutoCompleteField(textControl, new TextContentAdapter(), suggestions);
```

Comment: I am using both ComboViewer and Text element with ContentAdapter. Actually for this situation it does not matter - proposal popup with almost 200000 records will not work as well. It takes so much time to create this element. I got in my GUI couple of filters: you can imagine: first is Country, City, Street. You can select ALL for City for one country and you got 200000 streets.... In moment when I select 'ALL' for city my app is killed. So pagination is only possibility...